# AngularJS subtract (DueDateActual - DueDateForecaste) $scope consumed from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, scope

I am new to AngularJS and need some help finding the days between two dates.    I have two dates consumed from a JSON file and I want to find out the number of days between the two dates dynamically for each ID.  Below is what I have and I could use some help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body >
 <div ng-controller="SiteCtrl">
   <ul ng-repeat="site in sites">
     <li>{{site.ID}}</li>
     <li>{{dayDiff}}</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 </body>
<script>
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("SiteCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('JSON/getsamplesitesCopy.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {


    $scope.sites = data;

    $scope.dayDiff = $scope.sites.DueDateActual - $scope.sites.DueDateForecasted;


}).
   error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
   });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the result of `$scope.dayDiff`?

Comment: Also, possibly typo / error, you have `$scope.sites // plural` and also `$scope.site // singular`, so currently the latter is undefined

Comment: @azium the result is NaN.

Comment: Well that's not good. Here's a better question, what's the result of `data`?

Comment: @azium that was a typo.  I corrected it but still get NaN.

Comment: It seems that you're mixing data types. Is `data` an array, or an object?

Comment: [{"ID":"136",
 "DueDateForecasted":"2015-09-10",
 "DueDateActual":"2015-09-17",},{"ID":"133","DueDateForecasted":"2015-09-12",
 "DueDateActual":"2015-09-17",}
 ]

Comment: @azium it is an array from JSON that comes from a PHP file connected to MySQL.

Comment: you should have a look at [momentJs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) or some other date parsing library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your data:

```
data = [
  { 
     "ID": "136", 
     "DueDateForecasted": "2015-09-10",      
     "DueDateActual": "2015-09-17"
  },
  { ... }
]
```

You have an array of objects, such that:

```
$scope.sites = data // $scope.sites is also an array
$scope.sites.DueDateActual // undefined
$scope.sites[0].DueDateActual // "2015-09-17"
```

A note about dates. A date that is in string format such as `2015-09-17` is not going to give you a meaningful result when subtracting with another. Try typing `"test" - "test"` in your browser console. You guessed it, it's `NaN`. In order to properly do math with dates, you need to create a `new Date` object, passing your date string as an argument.

```
var dueDateActual = new Date($scope.sites[0].DueDateActual)
dueDateActual // Wed Sep 16 2015 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

var dueDateForecasted = new Date($scope.sites[0].DueDateForecasted)
dueDateActual - dueDateForecasted // -604800000
```

This will return milliseconds, so you'll need to convert that into days

In order to do this for every element in your array, you could `map` the array adding a field in the process.

```
$scope.sites = data.map(function (item) {
  var millisDiff = (new Date(item.DueDateActual) - new Date(item.DueDateForecasted))
  item.dayDiff = Math.floor(millisDiff / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ))
  return item
})
```

Then modify your `ng-repeat` slightly to include the diff on the repeated item.

```
<ul ng-repeat="site in sites">
  <li>{{site.ID}}</li>
  <li>{{site.dayDiff}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It does work but it only gives me the result of the first object for both.  How can I get the result for both? or multiple?

Comment: Please don't suggest parsing strings using the Date constructor, it is unreliable (the above will return NaN in IE8). **Always** manually parse strings.

Comment: @azium Thank you very much for you help!  It works but I did catch a small error you posted: item.dayDiff = millisDiff * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 but it should be: item.dayDiff = millisDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24).  I can't thank you enough for your help.  You have done me a huge favor!

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string dates to Date objects. You can use a library for that, or give it to the Date constructor (very much not recommended) or you can use a simple function like:

```
/*
**  @param  {string} s - Date string yyyy-mm-dd
**  @return {Date}     - Date object for 00:00:00 with system timezone offset
*/
function parseISODate(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(s[0], s[1]-1, s[2]);
}
```

and then:

```
$scope.dayDiff = parseISODate($scope.sites.DueDateActual) -
                 parseISODate($scope.sites.DueDateForecasted);
```

will return the difference in milliseconds between the two.

The parse function treats the date as local, which is consistent with ECMA-262 ed 6 and ISO 8601, but ES5 (e.g. new Date(string)) will parse it as UTC.

Comment: That really helped me! Thank you!